# In-App Purchase test fails on IOS 4.01, works on iOS 5+

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4, in-app-purchase

This is driving me crazy.

I'm trying to debug an App that uses In-App Purchase.

I use the following simple piece of code to get my products (I've got only one product):

```
NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:PRODUCT_ID];       
SKProductsRequest *request = [[[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers] autorelease];
request.delegate = self;
[request start];
```

On devices running iOS5 and above, I get my product back in the `response.products` property of `productsRequest:didReceiveResponse:`. I can also place an order (using a test user) on these devices.

On a device running iOS 4.01, I get an empty array in `response.products` and my product id in `response.invalidProductIdentifiers`. If I try to ignore the product information and call  `addPayment:` on this device using the same product id, I'm getting `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed` in `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:`.

Obviously my setup is correct, since things work flawlessly on my iOS5+ devices.

I also checked and tried everything in http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/ to no avail.

Any ideas? Do you think it's safe for me to submit the App under this situation?

Answer (score 0):

This right here helped me out when I was debugging a similar problem - http://teewe.com/2011/10/24/ios-in-app-purchase-programming-troubleshooting-guide-continuously-updating/

Comment: Thanks... but unfortunately this checklist is rather trivial and doesn't apply in my case.

Comment: How about the walkthrough? http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

Comment: Thanks. As I said, it does work in iOS 5+. In any case I read the walkthrough and I've done everything, no new insight.